# Split series of strings with spaces by a semi-colon

Tags: formula, picklist

Trying to split picklist formula output with a semi-colon, here is current code:

```
IF(ISBLANK(Products__c),NULL, 
SUBSTITUTE(TRIM( 
IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "not applicable"),"not applicable ",NULL)& 
IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "chameleon"),"chameleon ",NULL)&   
IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "pay-gateway"),"pay-gateway ",NULL)&   
IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "branded URL"),"branded URL ",NULL)&   
IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "b4promo (RLP)"),"b4promo (RLP) ",NULL)&   
IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "b4mailer"),"b4mailer ",NULL)& 
IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "b4arrival (OCI)"),"b4arrival (OCI) ",NULL)& 
IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "email shopping cart"),"email shopping cart ",NULL)," ","; "))
```

The problem is with "not applicable", "email shopping cart", "b4promo (RLP)" and "b4arrival (OCI), all of which have a space in them. The output it gives is

```
"email; shopping; cart"
```

where it should be

```
"email shopping cart;"
```

Comment: what about `b4arrival (OCI)`, how it is coming?

Comment: @Liam do you need to merge your unregistered account ? it appears as if you are editing your own question as another user.

Comment: @liam, let me know if my answer works for you

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try this logic. Put a `*` at the end of each product and then replace the `*` with `;`

```
IF(ISBLANK(Products__c),NULL, 
SUBSTITUTE(TRIM( 
    IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "not applicable"),"not applicable *",NULL)& 
    IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "chameleon"),"chameleon *",NULL)&   
    IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "pay-gateway"),"pay-gateway *",NULL)&   
    IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "branded URL"),"branded URL *",NULL)&   
    IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "b4promo (RLP)"),"b4promo (RLP) *",NULL)&   
    IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "b4mailer"),"b4mailer *",NULL)& 
    IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "b4arrival (OCI)"),"b4arrival (OCI) *",NULL)& 
    IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "email shopping cart"),"email shopping cart *",NULL),"*","; ")
)
```

Or, without any substitute, put `;` at end of each product.

```
IF(ISBLANK(Products__c),NULL,  
    IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "not applicable"),"not applicable ;",NULL)& 
    IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "chameleon"),"chameleon ;",NULL)&   
    IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "pay-gateway"),"pay-gateway ;",NULL)&   
    IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "branded URL"),"branded URL ;",NULL)&   
    IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "b4promo (RLP)"),"b4promo (RLP) ;",NULL)&   
    IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "b4mailer"),"b4mailer ;",NULL)& 
    IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "b4arrival (OCI)"),"b4arrival (OCI) ;",NULL)& 
    IF(INCLUDES(Products__c, "email shopping cart"),"email shopping cart ;",NULL)
)
```

2nd one is more preferable.